# Unit testing a protected static new method in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, static, scope, protected

I'm trying to write a wrapper class for a protected method which I wish to unit test. The problem in my case is that the original method is declared as `protected static new` which prevents me from accessing the base method because it's static.

Is there any other way to write this wrapper method? If not which other options do I have to unit test this method without changing its scope?

EDIT: Code Added:

```
public class DerivedClassToTest : BaseClass
{
    protected static new Type_A MehodeToTest()
    {
        Type_A A = new Type_A
        {
            //DoSomething...
        };
        return A;
    }
}
```

How do i test **MehodeToTest**?

I tried to derive from the **DerivedClassToTest** in my Unitest so i can access the Protected methode but its static so i cant call **base.MethodeToTest**. How do i access the **MethodeToTest**

Thank you.

Comment: You have especially bad architecture for unit testing: 1) static methods 2) hidden methods with `new` keyword...

Comment: From what you describe, it should work fine. Please show the code that doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Kirill Polishchuk: I agree, but its a given Code (not new one) so refactoring at this point is involving too much changes, which is not wished since this code is allready in use.

Comment: I usualy dont UnitTest my `private-protected` methods. Only the the `public` ones.

Comment: @gdoron: Good for you, but this is not my question, anyway the normal way over public methods needs too much inializing so i start with the small functions, basically ur right but lets not go into this disscusion..

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk sadly enough, this is often the only way to start adding tests to code that is currently not under test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a wrapper in your unit test project to expose the method:

```
public class DerivedClassToTestWrapper : DerivedClassToTest
{
    public static Type_A MehodeToTestWrapped()
    {
        return DerivedClassToTest.MehodeToTest();
    }
}
```

and then in your unit test:

```
var actual = DerivedClassToTestWrapper.MehodeToTestWrapped();
```

Also I am not quite sure what was the design goal of using `protected static new` on a member but I must confess that I have never seen such access modifiers on a member so far.

Comment: It works, thank you, i was trying using the base.MehodeToTest() from within my static methode which is wrong. thanx again

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine, however the `base` qualifier works only with instance methods. You can access the static test method like you would any other static method:

```
public class HelperClassToAccessMethodeToTest : DerivedClassToTest
{
       public static Type_A MehodeToTestWrapped()        
       {            
           return DerivedClassToTest.MehodeToTest();        
       }  
}
```

FWIW, I think you are following the right path to "unlock" legacy code for testing this way.

Comment: Ur right, that was my mistak, i was trying the conventional way and didnt noticed the static issue, thank you.

Comment: You can just say `return MethodToTest();`. There's no need to qualify with the class name, but it's also no problem to do that. Your helper class inherits the method and does not hide it with a `new` method.